# Queue of variable length array or struct

Tags: c, queue

How would one go about creating a queue that can hold an array, more over an array with variable amounts of rows.

```
char data[n][2][50];
//Could be any non 0 n e.g:
n=1; data = {{"status","ok}};
// or
n=3; {{"lat", "180.00"},{"long","90.123"},{"status","ok}};
// and so on
```

n to be added to the queue. Or is there even a better solution than what I'm asking? A queue is easy enough to write (or find re-usable examples of) for single data items but I'm not sure what method I would use for the above. Maybe a struct? That would solve for array and n...but would it solve for variable array?

More broadly the problem I'm trying to solved is this.
I need to communicate with a web server using POST. I have the code for this already written however I don't want to keep the main thread busy every time this task needs doing, especially since I need to make other checks such as is the connection up, if it isn't I need to back off and wait or try and bring it back online.

My idea was to have a single separate dedicated to this task. I figured creating a queue would be the best way for the main thread to let the child thread know what to do.

The data will be a variable number of string pairs. like:

Main

```
//Currently does
  char data[MAX_MESSAGES_PER_POST][2][50];
  ...
  assembles array
  sendFunction(ptrToArray, n);
  resumes execution with large and un predicatable delay

//Hopefully will do
  ...
  queue(what needs doing)
  carry on executing with (almost) no delay
```

Child

```
while(0)
{
  if(allOtherConditionsMet())  //Device online and so forth
  {
    if(!empty(myQueue))
    {
       //Do work and deque
   }
 }
 else
 {
     //Try and make condition ok. Like reconect dongle.
 }
  // sleep/Back off for a while
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to write the queue from scratch? Its usually a bad idea to implement your own ADTs, when there are well tested, standard ones available. You'll spend time chasing subtle bugs, and generally writing the same code that somebody has written already. Did you consider using a library that provides a queue?

Comment: @ArjunShankar No, do you have an example or link to a library for C99 that solves my problem? I didn't find one, although I suppose that's more likely a result of my poor searching skills. Being that it's a hobby project, I wouldn't mind writing it myself, however you are right, a pre-tested lib is probably better.

Comment: @ArjunShankar While you are correct, most veteran programmers have accumulated their own library of production-quality ADTs over the years... so he might as well start working on it, the earlier the better. It is very strange, but there is no widely recognized ADT library for C, nothing like STL, Boost etc. I don't think Glib will ever get that kind of recognition, unless one of them Microsoft-sized companies adopts it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use an existing library, [like Glib](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GLib). GLib is cross platform. If you used [GLib's asynchronous queues](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Asynchronous-Queues.html), you'd do something like:

The first thread to create the queue executes:

```
GAsyncQueue *q = g_async_queue_new ();
```

Other threads can reference (show intent to use the queue) with:

```
g_async_queue_ref (q);
```

After this, any thread can 'push' items to the queue with:

```
struct queue_item i;
g_async_queue_push (q, ( (gpointer) (&i)));
```

And any thread can 'pop' items from the queue with:

```
struct queue_item *d = g_async_queue_pop (q);
/* Blocks until item is available.  */
```

Once a thread finishes using the queue and doesn't care any more about it, it calls:

```
g_async_queue_unref (q);
```

Even the thread which created the queue needs to do this.

There are a bunch of other useful functions, which you can all read about on [the page documenting them](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Asynchronous-Queues.html). Synchronization (locking/consistency/atomicity of operations) is taken care of by the library itself.

Comment: This looks promising and probably the best answer, but I ended up using http://code.google.com/p/c-pthread-queue/source/browse/trunk/queue.h instead. The q_async_queue_new() shown above didn't work for me and I couldn't for the life of me get it to work.